# populate listview image with path in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, listview, data-binding

I've got a listview, which holds a bitmap (imagebutton) and details of the video. When I load the page this list should populate. All the details of the video clip populates, but no image is displayed. I store the images and videos in a folder, and the path of the images in a sql database. How do populate the image in the imagebutton? This is what I've done:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvlist" >
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                               <br />
                               <div style="height:100px;">
                                    <a href="PlayVideo.aspx?vid=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>">
                              <asp:ImageButton id="imgVidThumbnail" runat="server" AlternateText="Watch"
                                     ImageAlign="left" Width="150" Height="120px" style="margin-bottom:10px;  margin-left: 32px; margin-right:15px;"
                                     ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ThumbPath") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ThumbPath") %>'/>
                                       </a>
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Title: " CssClass="ltrTitle" Width="100px" ></asp:Label>
                                   <asp:Label ID="ltrTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FileTitle") %>' CssClass="ltrTitle" Width="300px" ></asp:Label>
                                   <br />
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Date Uploaded: " CssClass="ltrTitle" Width="100px" ></asp:Label>
                                   <asp:Label ID="ltrDateUploaded" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DateUploaded") %>' CssClass="ltrTitle" Width="200px" ></asp:Label>
                                   <br />
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Description: " CssClass="ltrTitle" Width="120px" ></asp:Label>
                                   <div id="div" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto; width:75%; max-width:75%; height:55px; max-height:55px; word-break:break-all; background-color:ghostwhite;" runat="server"> 
                                   <asp:Label ID="ltrDescription" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>' CssClass="ltrTitle" Width="75%" ></asp:Label>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                               <br /> <br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>

    private void BindList()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RoadHogzConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from VideoInfo", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "Video");
        Session["videos"] = ds;
        lvlist.DataSource = GetVideoList("Select * FROM VideoInfo");
        lvlist.DataBind();
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
The path will change from month to month.. the only part that will stay the same is uploads and the last folder: the folder path will be like \uploads\Year\Month\thumb - month and year will change every month and every year.....

Edit:
My view source of the path gives out extra characters: this is the method to display image here then it gives me the below code: ImageUrl ='<%= ResolveClientUrl(Eval("ThumbPath"))%>'

```
    <a href="PlayVideo.aspx?vid=1038">
                              <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$lvlist$ctrl1$imgVidThumbnail" id="MainContent_lvlist_imgVidThumbnail_1" src="<%=%20ResolveClientUrl(Eval("ThumbPath"))%>" alt="Watch" align="left" style="height:120px;width:150px;margin-bottom:10px;  margin-left: 32px; margin-right:15px;" />
                                       </a>
```

With this ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ThumbPath") %>'  it displays the correct path in source view, but still no image....

Comment: Do you want the path to show in the list or you want the image located at the path to show?

Comment: How you are storing Image path in SQL. If it is virtual path like ~/Uploads/..  then try using ImageUrl ='<%= ResolveClientUrl(Eval("ThumbPath"))%>'

Comment: @CathalMF I want the image located at the path to show

Comment: @Vishal Vaishya, Yes it is a virtual path ~Uploads//2013//June//thumb, that method isn't working, still no image displayed...

Comment: Can you simply try with img tag? <img src='<%= ResolveClientUrl(Eval("ThumbPath"))%>' /> in your ItemTemplate. If this do not show you any image then problem is with your path or image. Also, ~Uploads//2013//June//thumb is not a valid path, hope it is something like : ~/Uploads/2013/June/thumb/xyz.jpg

Comment: @Vishal Vaishya, that doesn't work either... I took the entire path: C:\Users\name\Documents\Newfolder\Hogz\Hogz\uploads\2013\Jun\Thumb\7562.jpg and pasted it in the search programs and files and it opened correctly and fine, doesn't look like there is any problem, how can I find out whether it is the path or the image?

Comment: Is your project under same directory Hogz? if not check with Permissions Documents folder is always with highest credentials. Secondly, check your html (view-source) and see what path is getting in this IMG tag. (if possible share it). If using chrome press F12 and under console tab check error message for IMG path if any.

Comment: Yes for the moment it is until I deploy the website to the server... My view source gives extra characters which isn't in the path, this may be the problem, but how do I fix this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31227/discussion-between-vishal-vaishya-and-user2042152)

Comment: @Vishal Vaishya, Thank you so much for your help! could you please post the virtual comment so that I can mark it as an answer... It was never a virtual path, so all I done was to convert the path to virtual path and saved that into the database. It works now...

Answer (score 0):

Saving the path as a virtual path without server mappath. ~/.. instead of c:/, 
The rest of the code works fine.